# How to convert a Type (from TemplateHaskell) to a Proxy?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm neck deep in some complex TemplateHaskell and am desperately looking for a function with the following type signature:

```
Language.Haskell.TH.Type -> Data.Proxy.Proxy a
```

Does something like this exist? I can appreciate that it would be hard to determine the type `a` in the type-sig given above, but is there no way that that the compiler can look at what is inside `Type` and figure out what `a` should be?

Here's more context of the overall problem I'm trying to solve: I've "de-structured" a record-type via TH and have a value of `[Type]`, where each element in the list corresponds to a field in the record. I need to pass each of these types to an existing function that takes only a `Proxy a`. If it makes things easier, the original record already has an instance of `Generic`

Comment: There is no way to write this function. Haskell does not support dependant types.

Answer (score 1):

You want a function that, given a type, produces *an expression* for a `Proxy` for that type.

```
proxyFor :: Type -> Exp
proxyFor = SigE (ConE 'Proxy) . AppT (ConT ''Proxy)
```

e.g.

```
ghci> let x = $(return $ proxyFor (ConT ''Int)) in x
Proxy
```

You can `map` `proxyFor` over your `[Type]`, get a `[Exp]`, and apply them to your function.